# how can I export Eclipse addins and Java Syntax colouring configuration

Tags: eclipse

how can I export eclipse java syntax colouring configuration from one machine to another?

I remember these are saved in a file somewhere.

Also is there a quick way to export Eclipse plugins from one machine to another?
or more precisely synchronize plugins (as to add the missing ones)

Kind Regards

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: sorry I thought I answered your comment: Windows XP